# How to make a UiTextField Frame that automatically adjusts

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

I'm trying to make a UiTextField Frame that will resize according to screen size and orientation, but I am not having much success. (Frame as in uitextfieldname.frame(x:*,y:*,width:*,height:*) Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Get label node from scene and store it for use later

    let animateList = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1.0), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0), SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)])

    let startScreen = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica Neue UltraLight")
    startScreen.text = "Welcome"
    startScreen.fontSize = 100.0
    startScreen.fontColor = SKColor.white
    startScreen.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(startScreen)
    startScreen.alpha = 0.0



    startScreen.run(animateList)

    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false) { _ in
        startScreen.text = "I don't belive we have met before"

        startScreen.run(animateList)

    }

    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false) { _ in
        startScreen.text = "What's your name?"

        startScreen.run(animateList)

    }

    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15.0, repeats: false) { _ in
        let name = UITextField()
        //name.frame = CGRect(x: ,y: ,width: , height: )
    }
}

}
```

P.S

Important/relevant code at base

Comment: What do you mean, *the important/relevant code is at base*?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `autolayout` constraint `pinned leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints` and set `numberofLines = 0` in order to adjust the frame.